# Different behavior when python script is run by IDLE and run by double clicking

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I found that my simple python script whose objective is to run sub_script in parallel worked properly when I executed it by the python IDLE (GUI). But it went wrong when I double clicked it in window and executed the sub_script one by one instead of running them all in once. I post my code below. May anyone give me some advice?

```
import time, multiprocessing, os, abc

rootdir=os.getcwd()
NProc = 6

def wrapfunc(args)
    return args[0](*args[1:])


if __name__== '__main__':

    print('abc Starts.')
    ti=time.time()
    pool1=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NProc)
    Childs1 = [[abc.abc, dirpath, filename]
                for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(rootdir)
                for filename in filenames
                if filename.endswith('.inp')]
    pool_map1 = pool1.map_async( wrapfunc, Childs1 )
    pool1.close()
    pool_map1.wait()
    print('The abc takes {0} to finish.'.format(time.time()-ti))
```

**EDIT 1 : Two images was added. 2013/10/27 11:33a.m. UTC+8:00**

[Image1: Start by python IDLE (GUI)](http://upload.lsforum.net/users/public/v26226abc-IDLEw156.jpg)  <-Pop out all windows to run in parallel.

[Image2: Start by double clicking (command line)](http://upload.lsforum.net/users/public/i37258abc-doublickl156.jpg) <-Queue up and run it one by one.

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: There is no traceback. Maybe I have confused you. 
The script started by both methods can run properly. 
But only when the script started by python IDLE (GUI) can pop up 6 windows simultaneously to run in parallel. While the script started by double clicking (command line), the script will queue up to run.
Let me include some pictures to help you figure my problem.( See above again)